# Проблемы с запуском проекта в RAD XE3

Tags: radstudio, delphi-xe3

Существует группа проекта, куда включены несколько внешних библиотек и основные исходники. Когда что-то меняешь в подключаемой библиотеке - все норм, проект компилится и запускается в отладке без проблем. Если исправил что-то в основном исходнике - компиляция проходит нормально, после чего проект якобы стартует и все останавливается. При нажатии на Program Reset RAD виснет. Закрываем его. Открываем заново - запускаем проект в отладке, все ок. 
Это сильно усложняет работу. Может кто-то сталкивался - как быть, в чем может быть проблема ?

Answer (score 1):

Оказалось (возможно, кому-то будет полезна эта информация), что дело в навесе AQTime от SmartBear. Снес эту надстройку - все работает без проблем и запускается, и отладка, и все, что нужно. 
Однако, это надстройка идет вместе с дистрибутивом студии, который я использовал... и ставится почти автоматом.